# How to find index in list by search

Tags: python, list

```
['16:False,', '15:False,', '17:True,']
```

I need to know the index of str with true value

It is at index 2 but how do i make code like this for that

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're asking for, but this will return the index of all items in the list with "True" in them:

```py
my_list = ['16:False,', '15:False,', '17:True,']

indexes = [idx for idx, s in enumerate(my_list) if "True" in s]

print(indexes)

>>> [2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```py
def find_true_index(lst):
    for index, elem in enumerate(lst):
        if 'True' in elem:
            return index
    return None

l = ['16:False,', '15:False,', '17:True,']

print(find_true_index(l))
```

It will return the index if it found it and `None` if it didn't. Although be careful as this will always only find the first occurance, it might be useful to add all the wanted indexes to the list and then return the list.

Comment: `enumerate` is more Pythonic.

Comment: "Pythonic" is such a dumb term in my opinion. I see people chaining maps, zips and other list operators just to produce code that is less efficient and less readable, all in the name of being idiomatic. But I do agree that enumerate is probably the better choice here.

Comment: I wouldn't say being less readable is idiomatic. "Readability counts" is part of the [Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/).

Comment: I agree, true idiomatic python is joy to read, but the problem is it requires practice. Issues arise when people take it too far with the "pythonisms" and miss the mark completely.

Comment: If it's not relatively easy to read it's unlikely to be idiomatic (or Pythonic. I'd say the two terms should be interchangeable).

Answer (score 0):

Try `next()`:

```py
lst = ["16:False,", "15:False,", "17:True,"]


i = next((i for i, s in enumerate(lst) if "True" in s), None)
print(i)
```

Prints:

```
2
```

---

If `"True"` isn't found, `i` is set to `None`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension and the [in](https://www.afternerd.com/blog/python-string-contains/) command as such,

```
my_list = ['16:False,', '15:False,', '17:True,']
idx = [i for i, ele in enumerate(my_list) if "True" in  ele]

print(idx)
```

The comprehension clocks through your list & takes note of the indices where the element, `ele` contains the string "True".

If there is more than one entry then you will get a list of indices, if there are no entries then you will get an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```py
import numpy as np

l = ['16:False,', '15:False,', '17:True,']

np.where(['True' in x for x in l])[0]

#> array([2])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def get_true_index_list(data: list, only_first=False):
    trues_list = []
    for i, v in enumerate(data):
        if 'True' in v:
            true_index = int(v.split(':')[0])
            if only_first:
                return (i, true_index) 
            trues_list.append((i, true_index)
    return trues_list
r1 = get_true_index_list(['16:True,', '15:False,', '17:True,'])
r2 = get_true_index_list(['16:False,', '15:False,', '17:True,'], only_first=True)
print(r1)
print(r2)
```

Result :

```py
([(0,16),(2,17)])
(2,17)
```

Here, first value of tuple is lists's index and second value is int value in "True"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the answer in a list.

```
given_list = ['16:False,', '15:False,', '17:True']

for i in range(0, len(given_list)):
    if "True" in given_list[i]:
        print i
```